# "Could not resolve host" when trying to connect to Stripe's API

Tags: laravel, docker, dns, stripe-payments, alpine-linux

As the title says there are some DNS issues and **sometimes** when I try to curl inside my docker container `https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents` it returns `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com`. This issue does not happen if I try to curl other websites.

```
docker exec -it php-alpine /bin/sh

/var/www/html # curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents
{ works. some json response }

/var/www/html # curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com

/var/www/html # curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com

/var/www/html # curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents
{ works. some json response }

/var/www/html # curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: api.stripe.com

/var/www/html # curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/setup_intents
{ works. some json response }

and so on...
```

However when I exit my docker image this issue does not happen. I can curl that address hundreds of times on my Ubuntu system (working on WSL) and it has never gave me any error before.

I tried to curl that address simultaneously from my local Ubuntu system, and from the docker image and while everything worked on Ubuntu, I was still getting the same error in the docker image.

Comment: If your code works as expected, this is simply a matter of your network configuration, and is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

login to docker container and open this file `/etc/resolv.conf` and add this line inside:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

or just run this inside container:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: more than welcome, anytime.

Comment: And why specifically this nameserver and not any other? This is cargo cult "programming", without explaining. It may be a short term win but does not really solve anything in the long run, if DNS queries are not working correctly in this container setup.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek you're right because now docker aliases do not work since I changed the DNS server. Any other solutions?

Comment: i had the same issue with stripe before, it was solved by adding two nameservers related to google to my resolv config that's why i offered that solution it was solved by adding `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Comment: Nevermind, instead of adding the nameserver to the resolv.conf file I had to do it in the `docker-compose.yml` file and now everything works including docker aliases :)

Comment: "and now everything works" ... if you are happy sending all your internal DNS activity to an external party, yes. The real solution is to have your DNS queries work locally, that is by using either a local nameserver such as `unbound`, or some trusted one (your ISP one if you trust it, or another one you control). Especially since you said "sometimes there are issues",  and it is not normal it is sometimes.